# Is there any way to only import the MNIST images with 0's and 1's?

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5, mnist

I am just starting out with tensorflow and I want to test something only on the 0's and 1's from the MNIST images. Is there a way to import only these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using

`from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`

No, there is no function or argument in that file... What you can do is load all data, and select only the ones and zeros.

Comment: Sorry that was not clear, but yes I am using that line.